# Razor html-output not as expected

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**My .cshtml code:**

```
<p>@(
    building.Devices.Any() ? 
    string.Format("<b>{0}</b>: {1}", Localization.DevicesCount, building.Devices.Count) : 
    Localization.NoDevices
)</p>
```

**My html-output:**

```
<p>&lt;b&gt;Anzahl Geräte&lt;/b&gt;: 1</p>
```

**But I want this:**

```
<p><b>Anzahl Geräte</b>: 1</p>
```

**Question:**

What can I do to print my string with HTML tags and not as I did?

*Thank you for the help in advance.*

Comment: if possible, instead of using <b> tag, you should use css.In addition, all these format should be able to be done in the controller instead of doing them in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(...)` instead of `@(...)` but realize you won't be HTML encoding. In this case it looks perfectly safe but if you were outputting user supplied data you would want to HTML encode anything the user supplies.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. :) I know that this case isn't really safe but the variables are all constants on the server ;)

Comment: Great. I'll add that context matters too. This is HTML content context, but there is HTML attribute context, CSS, JavaScript, etc. Checkout the [XSS prevention cheat sheet here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).